# What is the fastest way to encode a bytebuffer image in jpg format?

Tags: java, android, kotlin, android-mediacodec, android-camerax

I use [CameraX](https://developer.android.com/training/camerax) to capture an image from the camera using [ImageAnalysis](https://developer.android.com/training/camerax/analyze). The image is received as 3 ByteBuffers (respectively for the Y, U and V planes). I only keep the Y plane ByteBuffer. The other 2 are discarded.

I would like to reduce the size of this ByteBuffer, for example by encoding it in the jpg format.

Is it better to use **MediaCodec** or **BitmapFactory**? Knowing that the encoding time should be as small as possible. Is there another (better or faster) solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A somewhat efficient way to do that is first converting your `YUV_420_888` image to `NV21`, then use Android's `YuvImage#compressToJpeg` API to convert it.

For the `YUV_420_888` -> `NV21` conversion, you can see the code sample [here](https://github.com/androidx/androidx/blob/6ca377f0b2acb8305a38cbe512a96256944c713d/camera/camera-core/src/main/java/androidx/camera/core/internal/utils/ImageUtil.java#L143). The performance of this step can be optimized by using `libyuv` for the format conversion: https://chromium.googlesource.com/libyuv/libyuv

For compressing `NV21` to `JPEG` with `YuvImage`, you can see the code sample [here](https://github.com/androidx/androidx/blob/420648a3c8ed86bac820aa39536c46a0beec22f3/camera/camera-core/src/main/java/androidx/camera/core/internal/YuvToJpegProcessor.java#L170).